Append (reuse data) doesn't work anymore for Geometry Nodes in Blender 4.2?
If you you do the following in Blender 4.2:

You add a grid
You add a monkey
You apply a geometry nodes modifier to the grid
In the geometry nodes modifier you insert an "Instance on Points" node
You connect an "object info" node to the "instance" socket
You select the monkey as the object in the "object info" node
You make a NodeGroup out out of these two nodes called "Monkey Grid"

After this you mark the grid object as an asset and select "Append (reuse data)" as the import method in the preferences.
If you then open a new file and drag this object in your scene with the asset browser (follow preferences or append (reuse data), it will create a duplicate of the monkey object and the NodeGroup every time you drag it into your scene again (.001, .002, .003, etc.)
Strangely enough, for the materials it seems to do it properly and use the same material with the same name again.
If I do the exact same thing in Blender 4.1 it reuses the the same monkey object and the same NodeGroup and does not create duplicates.
This has enormous implications on the size of your file, and I don't understand if this is a bug or if I am missing something here...


Blender file attached:


They list every single change present in each new version release notes. Have you checked those yet?

In the release notes, under Geometry Nodes, I found this line under Node Tools.
Data-block (collection, object, material, image) inputs are now supported, with the limitation that data-blocks from separate library files with non-unique names cannot be used (65803f262f).
I read the thread it is referring to, but I can't seem to understand what it means.
It seems to be only about Node Tools.
Should I file a bug report?

I think this has more to do with Asset Browser functionality than Node tools specifically.

I can't find anything about the asset browser in the release notes. I have been looking for a solution for half a day now.  :-)
Any ideas would be very welcome. Thanks in advance

Could you try referencing Suzanne in your example via Group Input instead of specifying it explicitly in Geometry Nodes graph and see if problem reproduces in this case?

Like this you mean? https://imgur.com/a/A1Ui08i
It doesn't seem to make a difference. It creates a duplicate of Suzanne, even tho the duplicate is an instance. It also creates a duplicate of the NodeGroup, which is not an instance.

I filed a bug report for it.
